# Facebook Applinks doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile-browser, applinks

Tried to work with applinks and my app was not invoked. I put the below content in my sample HTML page and tried to invoke my app on page load. But it doesn't work.

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="xyz://docs" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="1234" />

<meta property="al:android:url" content="xyz://docs" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.xyz.abc" />
```

The custom scheme seams to work fine and my app is invoked when i type xyz://docs from the chrome and safari browser.

When the sample page is loaded in the browser, I wanted my app to be invoked. Later I wanted the app to fallback once this works.

Note : The app_store_id, custom scheme and android:package in the above tags are properly configured in my test page.

Comment: When you say "the sample page is loaded in the browser", do you mean a browser like Safari? Safari does not support app links, so it won't auto invoke your app.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Guess works on Chrome in Android?. But din't work as well. Am I missing any more tags?

Comment: Chrome doesn't support app links either. The Facebook app itself supports it, so if you post a link in a status update, it will allow users to open your app.

Comment: @Ming Li, I am stuck on the same problem as Sam here. Maybe things have changed since July, but when I have registered my app in my plist file URL scheme "myappname://" and when i put that into URL field in Safari on my iPhone, my app is launched. I have added the meta tags to my home HTML page and published a story to FB newsfeed. When i tap on the story, my home page is loaded but my app does not launch. My scheme is "myappname" in plist, my iOS:url meta tag is "myappname://. This alone i would think should launch my app from FB newsfeed. any ideas what i'm missing?

Comment: Just verify if the link for the store has the custom scheme "myappname://". If thats URL thats invoked when tapping on the story in FB feed, then the app should be launched. If app not installed, app store for that app will be shown for the user to install the app.